# Unable to find which mandatory date field value is not set while saving in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have multiple objects inside the main object, I am getting below exception when I am trying to save changes in Entity Framework.

> The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.

I know this is because one of the mandatory date field value not set, but I am not getting which date field it is from the list of all objects in the main object. Is there any way to find that object and related date property?

Comment: The problem here is you need to identify which field is not set. That's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging the SQL should hopefully help you identify the problem. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception